# How to flip hierarchical clustering nodes in pheatmap

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, pheatmap

I have the following code:

```
pheatmap::pheatmap(mtcars, clustering_method = "ward.D2")
```

Which produces the plot like below.

[image]

What I'd like to do is to do these:

1. Move the `mpg` and `qsec` node to after `wt`.
2. Move `disp` and `hp` node to the leftmost.

Is that a valid thing to do? If so how can I achieve that?

***Update***

Following Marco Sandri suggestion below and with a little bit of
tweek. I came up with this code that does the job:

```
phtmap <- pheatmap::pheatmap(mtcars)
col_dend <- phtmap[[2]]
col_dend <- dendextend::rotate(col_dend, order = c("hp", "disp",   "vs", "am", "cyl", "drat", "gear", "carb","wt", "mpg","qsec") )
pheatmap(mtcars, cluster_cols=as.hclust(col_dend))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
library(pheatmap)
library(seriation)
library(dendextend)

phtmap <- pheatmap(mtcars)
col_dend <- phtmap[[2]]
col_dend <- rotate(col_dend, order = rev(names(mtcars)[get_order(col_dend)]))

# The pheatmap with the same clustering of heatmaply
pheatmap(mtcars, cluster_cols=as.hclust(col_dend))
```

[image]

Comment: @Marco_Sandri Thanks. But I can't find a package that gives `rotate()` function. `library(seriation)` seems to don't do it. Please advice.

Comment: @Marco_Sandri Thank you. Is the package `seriation` necessary there?